# How to create ads using google adwords API?

Tags: google-ads-api

Basically, I have a list of keywords, such as:

```
- red balloons
- free red balloons
- buy red balloons
- blue balloons
- ....
```

for each keyword, I have a list of 3-4 ads, each ad consisting of a title, line 1, line 2, and a url, e.g:

> Title: Free red balloons!
>
> Line 1: Buy free red balloons right now!
>
> Line 2: No hidden fees!
>
> Url: http://example.com

I have 3-4 such ads for every keyword.

Using the API, I want to:

```
1) Create an adgroup for every keyword
2) Under the adgroup, upload all the ads for that particular keyword. 
   So all the ads for `free red balloons` would go under that keyword's adgroup.
```

I'm looking for some general pointers/links to API pages for the methods which I'll need to use to accomplish this. Specifically I'm using PHP and the Apility library, but non-php specific info will also be very much welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CampaignService](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201406/CampaignService)

[AdGroupService](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201406/AdGroupService)

[AdGroupAdServie](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201406/AdGroupAdService)

Comment: [AdGroupAdService](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201406/AdGroupAdService); [AdGroupSevice](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201406/AdGroupService); [CampaignService](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201406/CampaignService)

Answer (score 3):

Using AdGroupService you would have to create ad group for each keyword. Of course you need to have parent campaign for that ad group.

Then using AdGroupCriterionService you would have to create keywords for each ad group.

And at last with AdGroupAdService place specified ads under appropriate ad group.

Using default AdWords clients this task is difficult because you need to create all that objects that are then being serialized into SOAP message.

If you are building your app on .NET platform, 
you might wanna take a look at GemBox.Ppc [AdWords API for .NET](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/Ppc/Overview.htm).

It dramatically simplifies management of AdWords objects.

Answer (score 1):

APIlity has been deprecated, as it only handles v13 of the AdWords API. To make your coding easier, you should probably be looking at the new [PHP Client Library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-adwords-php/), which offers full support for v200909, the latest API version. Be sure to check the 'examples' folder in the client library for some samples.

Answer (score 1):

To connect with google adwords api use [client library](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/clientlibraries?hl=pl) and see [code examples](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/clientlibraries?hl=pl). Read guides [here](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/start?hl=pl).

Long story short:

1. [Create campaign](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/6.5.0/examples/AdWords/v201509/BasicOperations/AddCampaigns.php).
2. [Add AdGroup to campaign](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/6.5.0/examples/AdWords/v201509/BasicOperations/AddAdGroups.php) for each keyword.
3. [Add Keywords to AdGroups](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/6.5.0/examples/AdWords/v201509/BasicOperations/AddKeywords.php).
4. [Add Ads to AdGroups](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/6.5.0/examples/AdWords/v201509/BasicOperations/AddTextAds.php).

Comment: Even though the links point to a 404 - this is extremely helpful because it spells out the correct workflow.